# How to keep tracking for entities selected by base type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a base entity and more than 20 entites are derived from this base entity.
Here a sample of my entities;

```
Base -> Desc { Id, Description, Code } 
Derived from Desc -> DescCity { Plate } 
Derived from Desc -> DescSex 
Derived from Desc -> DescNationality
```

and more...

Now I am selecting all my entites as Base type without OfType() method and without casting.

When I select an entity by Id or Description or any other property with .Where(x=>x.....) function everything is seems ok. But if want to create an entity like Person { Name="Baran", DescSex = (DescSex)selectDescById(1) } the problem begins...
Lets see the selectDescById function;

```
public void selectDescById(int id){ return db.Desc.Where(x=>x.Id==id).FirstOrDefault(); }
```

When I cast the returned Desc object to DescSex type Entity Framework loses the tracking of the entity and recreates the selected DescSex entity (which one I selected before from the db). And on each new Person EF inserts new DescSex entity.

How can I fix this problem without writing a select function for each derived types? Is there a way to keep tracking? Thanks.